# Javascript regex to replace text div and &lt; &gt;

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var text='<div id="main"><div class="replace">&lt; **My Text** &gt;</div><div>Test</div></div>'
```

I want to replace div with class="replace" and html entities **`&lt; &gt;`**  comes inside that div with some other text.

I.e the output :

```
'<div id="main"> Hello **My Text** Hello <div>Test</div> </div>'
```

I've tried

```
var div = new RegExp('<[//]{0,1}(div|DIV)[^><]*>', 'g');
text = text.replace(div, "Hello");
```

but this will replace all div.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Do not parse HTML with regular expressions. Use a HTML parser.

Comment: @Krzysztof Hasiński its a string stored in variable text

Comment: @bios ...which contains html. Jquery would do this awesomely, if it's an acceptable solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @ Jan please give me some examples or links to refer

Comment: please check the out text contains **My Text** and i don't want to replace that

Comment: @Jan text var contains a string and it is not html code

Comment: @bios If you want to have a HTML code inside a string and want to parse it always use a parser. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html Here is an explanation why you should do it. It doesn't matter how do you initially store HTML document (or part of a HTML document). If it must be valid with XML/HTML structure use a parser, not regexp.

Comment: @bios Looks like a string containing html code to me. Read my answer again and see if it makes sense to you. It does exactly what you ask for.

Comment: @Jan I want to replace this "<div class="replace">&lt; &gt;</div>" but not the text inside that div. i.e
the result will be like this :
<div id="main">RelpaceString My Text RelpaceString <div>Test</div></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a Jquery solution is acceptable:

```
text = $(text) // Convert HTML string to Jquery object
         .wrap("<div />") // Wrap in a container element to make...
         .parent()        // the whole element searchable
         .find("div.replace") // Find <div class="replace" />
           .each(function()   // Iterate over each div.replace
           {
             $(this)
               .replaceWith($(this).html() // Replace div with content
                .replace("&lt;", "<sometext>")
                .replace("&gt;", "</sometext>")); // Replace text
           })
         .end().html(); // return html of $(text)
```

This sets `text` to:

```
<div id="main"><sometext> My Text </sometext><div>Test</div></div>
```

And to replace it back again:

```
text = text.replace('<sometext>', '<div class="replace">&lt;')
           .replace('</sometext>', '&gt;</div>');
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2
http://api.jquery.com/each/
http://api.jquery.com/find/
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: How to redo this i.e if the `text = '<div id="main"><sometext> My Text </sometext><div>Test</div></div>'` how to replace it with
`'<div id="main"><div class="replace">&lt; **My Text** &gt;</div><div>Test</div></div>'`

Comment: If I've changed the text into `var text='<p><div class="replace">&lt; My Text &gt;</div></p>'`, then replacing it with Jquery that set `text = "<p></p>"` as you explained above the result must be </sometext><p>My Text</sometext> </p>

Comment: I think the problem with my solution is that it only accepts valid html. `<p><div></div></p>` isn't valid html, `p` is an inline element and `div` is a block element. You can't have `block` elements inside `inline` elements in html.

Answer (score 2):

In pure JS it will be something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('replace');
var replaceTag = document.createElement('replacetext');
for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var e = elements[i];
    e.parentNode.replaceChild(replaceTag, e);
};​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one crazy regex which matches what you want:

```
var text='<div id="main"><div class="replace">&lt; **My Text** &gt;</div><div>Test</div></div>'

var r = /(<(div|DIV)\s+class\s*?=('|")\s*?replace('|")\s*?>)(\s*?&lt;)(.*?)(&gt;\s*?)(<\/(div|DIV)\s*?>)/g;
```

The whole replacement can be made with:

```
text.replace(r, function () {
         return 'Hello' + arguments[6] + 'Hello';
    });
```

Please let me know if there are issues with the solution :).

Btw: I'm totally against regexes like the one in the answer...If you have made it with that complex regex there's probably better way to handle the problem...

Comment: can you tlee me how to do the reverse of this i.e 
`<div id="main"> Hello **My Text** Hello <div>Test</div></div>`
to
`<div id="main"><div class="replace">&lt; **My Text** &gt;</div><div>Test</div></div>` 
i.e replace Hello with the removed div tags

Comment: `var r = /(<\s*(div|DIV)\s*(id|ID)\s*=\s*('|")main"\s*>)(.*?)((<\s*(div|DIV)\s*>)(.*?)(<\/\s*(div|DIV)\s*>)\s*(<\/\s*(div|DIV)\s*>))/;`
Something like that...And you should check the arguments of the callback of the replace method.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the DOM instead; you already have the structure you want, so swap out the node itself (borrowing heavily from [@maxwell's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13153564/36537), but moving children around as well):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('replace');
for(var i = elements.length-1; i>= 0; --i) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var newElement = document.createElement('replacetext');
    var children = element.childNodes;
    for(var ch = 0; ch < children.length; ++i) {
        var child = children[ch];
        element.removeChild(child);
        newElement.appendChild(child);
    }
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement,element);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

For each element of the given class, then, it will move each of its children over to the new element before using that element's position to insert the new element and finally removing itself.

My only questionmark is whether the modification of items in the array return by getElementByClassName will cause problems; it might need an extra check to see if the element is valid before processing it, or you may prefer to write this as a recursive function and process the tree from deepest node first.

It may seem like more work, but this should be faster (no re-parsing of the html after you've changed it, element moves are just reference value assignments) and much more robust. [Attempting to parsing HTML may damage your health.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Rereading the question (always a good plan), you begin with the text in a string. If that is truly the start point (i.e. you're not just pulling that out of an innerHTML value), then to use the above just create a temporary parent element:

```
var fosterer = document.createElement('div');
fosterer.innerHTML = text; // your variable from the question
```

And then proceed using `fosterer.getElementsByClassName`.